# Getting C2760 syntax error: unexpected token 'int', expected 'expression' for std::max<int>(...)

Tags: c++

I am trying to build a DLL with C exports for the [MathGeoLib](https://github.com/juj/MathGeoLib) library to be consumed from C#.

The code I've written so far:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "MathGeoLib/MathGeoLib.h"

OBB* OptimalEnclosingOBB(const vec* pointArray, int numPoints)
{
    const auto obb1 = OBB::OptimalEnclosingOBB(pointArray, numPoints);
    const auto obb2 = new OBB(obb1);
    return obb2;
}
```

The stdafx.h file:

```
#pragma once
#include "targetver.h"
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN             // Exclude rarely-used stuff from Windows headers
// Windows Header Files
#include <windows.h>
```

But when I compile, I get [the following error](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-errors-2/compiler-error-c2760?view=vs-2017) even though I defined `NOMINMAX`:

```
1>c:\build\mathgeolib\include\mathgeolib\geometry\quadtree.inl(699): error C2760: syntax error: unexpected token 'int', expected 'expression'
```

This is the line where Visual Studio 2017 is choking on:

https://github.com/juj/MathGeoLib/blob/master/src/Geometry/QuadTree.inl#L699

```
template<typename T>
int QuadTree<T>::NumNodes() const
{
    return std::max<int>(0, nodes.size() - 3); // The nodes rootNodeIndex+1, rootNodeIndex+2 and rootNodeIndex+3 are dummy unused, since the root node is not a quadrant.
}
```

**Question:**

How can I fix this error ?

Comment: Please provide [mcve] in the question itself, and not hidden behind links.

Comment: Updated my question :)

Comment: What's hiding in `stdafx.h`?

Comment: Oops, updated the question again !

Comment: it could be this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2789481/problem-calling-stdmax

Comment: where did you define NOMINMAX . Before or after including windows.h

Comment: @kmdreko I've already defined `NOMINMAX` and it effectively worked out for previous errors, trying to encompass `std::max` with parenthesis didn't help at all, the only that works is to remove `<int>` and it builds; however, I was hoping for a solution that wouldn't require to change the sources.

Comment: @rsjaffe I defined it in the project properties

Comment: you need `#include <algorithm>`,  also try `#undef max`

Comment: @M.M thank you, including `<algorithm>` solved the problem !

Comment: Also see [#define NOMINMAX using std::min/max](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13416418/608639), [std::min gives error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5004858/608639) and [Calling function with parenthesis around its name using C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19811452/608639).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line `#include <algorithm>` is required for use of `std::max` .